# Removing a variable in Python Gurobi

Tags: python, variables, addition, gurobi

I am using Python/Gurobi to optimize a problem. I generated variables using GRBaddVar through this code:

```
x[1,i,j,t] = model.addVar(vtype="B", name="x(1,%s,%s,%s)" % (i,j,t))
```

I also want to remove some variables in order to save some space. The variable is removed when a certain condition is true. Suppose the condition is when R = 1. To remove the variable I use the following code.

```
if R == 1:
    x[1,i,j,t] = model.delVars(vtype="B", name="x(1,%s,%s,%s)" % (i,j,t))
```

However, it resulted in the following error:

```
AttributeError: 'gurobipy.Model' object has no attribute 'delVars'
```

I have no idea what's wrong with the code since I just follow the documentation (attached below) from Gurobi. Thanks for your help!

[image: Gurobi Documentation: addVar]

[image: Gurobi Documentation: delVar]

Comment: You are using the python API, but referring to  the documentation for the C API.

Answer (score 0):

As David noted, you are looking at the documentation for the C API.

In the Python API, you can remove a single variable with the [Model.remove()](https://www.gurobi.com/documentation/current/refman/py_model_remove.html) method, using the Var object the argument. E.g.,

```
model.remove(x[1,i,j,t])
```

You can use this same method to remove, e.g., a list of Var objects at once.

Note that you should call [Model.update()](https://www.gurobi.com/documentation/current/refman/py_model_update.html) before removing variables in this manner.

Answer (score 0):

"You can use this same method to remove, e.g., a list of Var objects at once."
Can anyone suggest how to **remove** multiple variables at once. I have the variable to be removed in a dict/list format. I am trying to the below code, but error appears: **GurobiError: Item to be removed not a Var, MVar, Constr, MConstr, SOS, QConstr, or GenConstr**

`model.remove(var_to_remove_dict.keys())`

Comment: If you have a new question, please ask it by clicking the [Ask Question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/ask) button. Include a link to this question if it helps provide context. - [From Review](/review/late-answers/32279428)